# 12.04 to 14.04 music files with the wrong names

Tags: rhythmbox, music

Ok I just went from 12.04 to 14.04 and when I opened my music player (rhythmbox) all the songs wore messed up and had the wrong names. I un-installed the music player and re-installed it along with many other players and they all are listing the songs with the wrong names. How can I fix this with out re-naming over 2k songs?

Comment: Maybe a screenshot or an example. Upload a song and let us verify what your experiencing.

Comment: I would think you do not see the file names, but some id3 metainformation tags of the files, while the file names are unchanged. Can you show a list of some file names with `ls`, and describe how the names looked before the changes? Run `ls -l | head -n 10` in a directory containing some (or many) these files, and add the output to the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure by name OP meant title, not filename. Don't see how it'd be possible for upwards of 2000 mp3 files could be renamed after only updating